# How safe is to leave a open port on router without anything listening to it?

Tags: network

I'm using plex remote, and I have a double-NAT on my local network, so I need to open ports on the two routers.

As far I know, I have made secure connections to be required. And I don't plan to leave plex open all the time on my PC anyway. Just when I know I'll need it probably....

Is there any risk to leave those ports open ?

Comment: one risk might be attacking extra unwanted attention from port scanner operators, who might zoom-in on your machine because it looks encouraging at a glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/82488/why-is-it-bad-to-have-open-ports) including the accepted answer:

> A port isn't open if something isn't listening for a connection on it.
>
> The reason it is bad form to have all ports open to everywhere is that it exposes those services that are listening on those ports to exploits. That is why firewalls exist, to limit what is allowed to connect to certain ports, to reduce the surface area exposed by services.

To answer your question: There is no risk in opening ports if no services are listening on the port.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that! I always feared running services from LAN > WAN but I'm getting over it